# Gratis Android camera app, not linked with Google

Tags: gratis, android, camera

I am looking for a gratis Android photo app. I am happy enough with the built-in and would accept a clone; I just don’t want Google involved in my photos.

***Must have***

- Ability to store images on SD card
- Does not sync with the cloud in any way
- Switch between front & rear camera
- flash on/off/auto
- zoom

***Nice to have***

- A Windows companion app, to let me easily transfer my photo to my PC, preferably  also delete them.
- Panorama mode
- video mode
- redeye protection
- face detection
- sound off (mute)
- integrated QR app
- exposure length/aperture control
- long exposure timer
- timer before taking photo
- image stabilization

Basically, nothing too fancy (although I won’t complain about extra features). I don’t use FaceTweet, etc, and can edit on PC, rather than on the phone.

Just not Google.

Comment: Well, you could (and should) disable any auto cloud upload in the default camera and picture viewer apps.  Google makes Android anyway, on which your camera app would run; if they wanted to access your pics there's nothing you could do to prevent them.

Comment: When I disabled the Google camera app upload/synch, it told me that it doesn't have permission to delete photos on my SD card. I may never escape them completely, but I don't want to actively abet them

Comment: As long as you (any app you use) use Android and the camera API, Google will always be involved. Also probably only Google or the camera/phone vendor knows all the details of the hardware to make full use of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend **[Open Camera](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.sourceforge.opencamera/)** – which is available at F-Droid and meets all your must-have requirements. Your nice-to-haves are covered partly: there is a video mode, and you can adjust a lot of parameters. It has image stabilzation, face detection, timer, and more – but AFAIK no QR integration (at least I didn't see that).

The app is easy to use and has a pretty good quality. Using it myself for years, and am very satisfied with it.

[image: Open Camera]
<sup>*Open Camera* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera))</sup>

Some of your required features can be seen in this screenshot: using front/back camera, taking photos/videos (right "column"). The "lock" symbol lets you lock exposure while changing the motive/perspective, which I use e.g. if I later want to stitch panoramas from multiple shots.

Comment: Excellent! For my uses, this seems to be superior to the standard Google app. I love the grid and angle overlays.

Comment: Definitely! The fact it's available at F-Droid is an added plus for the privacy aware. I haven't played with all its features yet, it has quite a few :) Whenever asked for a camera app, this is what I recommend. Only waiting for the panorama feature. And I wish it had 16:9 in a reasonable resolution (not just 2MPx). The camera shipping with my BQ supports it for all its 4 resolutions (2,4,8,12MPx – miss 6MPx here) and has panorama – but it doesn't run on all devices. After flashing LOS I had to get an older version as the newest didn't work even there …

Comment: Issues I had with Open Camera in the past were: "View finder" was much too dark outside. Some settings are a bit complicated to change.